# iOS: Region monitoring with simulator is way off

Tags: ios, core-location

I've been having nothing but problems trying to do region monitoring on iPhone. First of all I have never (not even once) had either `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` fire on my iPhone 4 device.

I decided to test on the simulator instead of wasting work hours walking around downtown (although I would like to see this work in a real scenario). First of all, the simulator is way off in terms of accuracy, you'd think it'd be pretty accurate (or am I wrong to have assumed that?).

**The following was done in the simulator by changing the location under the Debug menu**

I finally got `didEnterRegion` to fire, though I was about 8 city blocks away from the circle in question. When I exited the region `didExitRegion` fired about 200 times in a row. Is this a simulator bug? I'm almost ready to give up on this and start calculating this stuff myself because it's getting ridiculous.

Any ideas as to why the accuracy is so bad and why my methods are being fired so many times?

Here's the relevant code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    CLLocationDegrees latitude = 45.50568;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = -73.57033;
    CLLocationCoordinates2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

    CLLocationDistance regionRadius = 200.0;

    CLRegion *myRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate radius:regionRadius identifier:@"aroundWork"];

    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:myRegion];

    return YES:
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Entered region: %@", region.identifier);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Exited region: %@", region.identifier);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, we have no way of knowing if what you are doing is correct (probably isn't though as many others have used these methods without problem) or a simulator bug.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I assume you are testing it on the simulator with a GPX file, as any other way would be wrong.

Now, because I have done extensive research on Region Monitoring:

Region monitoring is not very effective.
It can miss a region enter or exit easily.

We have done a lot of tests and a lot of walks and driven with our cars through the city multiple times to test.

Sometimes it works beautifully, sometimes it fails miserably.

I suggest you play around a bit with the region border (radius) settings and do REAL tests (walk or drive around certain points) to see which behaves better.

Our tests showed that smaller values behave better (100 to 200 meters radius) and also that the region monitoring behaves better when you are actually driving, rather than walking.

Remember it uses the cell tower antennas to position you, which is far less accurate than gps.

Comment: Well then would it be wiser to just look for a significant change in location, turn the GPS on once to get one location then turn it off immediately, then just calculate my own distance to circle centers to determine myself whether or not a user is inside or outside a specific region?? I don't exactly have to know if someone is exiting or entering, just if they're in a region or not. What do you think?

Comment: Significant location changes is using the exact same technology to find the users location, so I don't see why you would benefit from it more. If the app is open, then using gps at certain time intervals would be probably the best, however if you want to know the users location also when the app is on the background then I don't have to suggest a better way. I don't know if someone else knows something better...

Comment: the ideal region size actually differs from the iOS version you are using. While driving you probably cross the buffer area before the device fires a notification. While in the background the device does use the gps in a low power consumption mode. (which is why it appears in the location services as the little arrow indicating your app is using it)